# How hide database details when sql related exception occurs in Web Applicaition?

Tags: java, database, oracle, exception, struts

There is white hat(hacker) security scan in our Application. They asked us not to show database details in sqlExeption e.g

ERRMSG=Error: ORA-00001: unique constraint (PMS.SUBPROJACT_PK) violated, Connector 'oracle', Method -Update- (1);

In above error you can see Database table name as PMS and column as PMS.SUBPROJACT_PK

Now we are using struts framework and simply using ActionErrors and ActionError to show error message which ever error comes.

I have done some coding as of now, I am showing same custom message for all sqlExceptions. When my error String contain "ORA-" I am showing my message but I don't feel it as powerful solution.

Is there any way to hide or remove database details from SqlExeption with same error message?

Application - Web Application 
Framework - Struts1.x

Comment: You may want to override the methods for `ActionError` to only return the oracle error.

Comment: Even if override the method my " Exception e " object contains error message with database details also sometimes "ORA-001" sql errors get caught in RemoteException catch.

Also this ActionErrros method is getting call in 100s of function.

Comment: In theory you have a bunch of code in a try-catch. If you don't want to expose arbitrary exceptions, do something different in the catch handler. There's zero reason to send detailed error messages to the client in a production app.

Answer (score 0):

HI All Thanks for replies

I have understood that there is no such things to hide details of rom database from Exception.

As of now I am good with my above approach.

Also you guys are right we don't need to show anything related to exception to Client